# how to get line by line from txt file and replace variable

Tags: php, html, email

I want to replace `"\n"` by `"` in first line and last line of email

```
$chekclist = $_POST['emaillist'];
$rwina = explode("\n", "$chekclist");

$i = 0;
$count = 1;
foreach ($rwina as $key => $email[i])
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the desired output? **Provide a sample** of the input and the output.  Your code looks like it should do what you want....

Comment: not sure what you are asking but if u want to remove the same character from start and end then you could use `trim` function. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php] i don't think there is any need to use `explode` in your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you cannot do that because `\n` is where the line ends.

I'm assuming that you want your email to format like:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

But the text you'll get from `$_POST['emaillist']` will be format like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \n
consectetur adipiscing elit\n
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \n
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \n
```

So if you want to replace `\n` with `"` it will be like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
consectetur adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

But there is a way to achieve what you are looking for if I'm assuming it right :p

So here's the code:

```
$chekclist = $_POST['emaillist']; // Get email text
$rwina = explode("\n", "$chekclist"); // Make array
$count = count($rwina); // Count array values

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   if ($i == 0) {
       echo '"' . $rwina[$i] . '<br>';
   } else if ($i == ($count - 1)) {
       echo $rwina[$i] . '"<br>';
   } else {
       echo $rwina[$i]. '<br>';
   }
}
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply :) But i have another problem i have to add " in first and last of emailenter code here